# Uninstalling a program using wmic

Tags: windows, uninstallation, wmic

I have a program called FEKO installed on my machine. I want to uninstall it using wmic command from the command prompt.

But when I run the command it does not seem to uninstall it. I verified that I have FEKO installed on my system. What is the can be the problem ?

```
C:\Users\me>wmic product where "Name like '%FEKO%'" call uninstall
Executing (\\ME\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber="{90D43EF1-D5A0-4F66-   AB0D-200965758308}",Name="FEKO Suite",Version="6.2")->Uninstall()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
    ReturnValue = 1603;
 };
```

Comment: Maybe you need to open your command prompt as Administrator and try it again. Or simply use PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

`wmic` only uninstalls things if they were installed via Windows Installer.

See [WMI "installed" query different from add/remove programs list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673233/wmi-installed-query-different-from-add-remove-programs-list) for ways forward.