# If program exists uninstall

Tags: powershell, methods, uninstallation

I'm trying to understand the `.uninstall()` method.

From [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23d2196f-80d9-4a9b-bcff-5cfbea2b7cba/powershell-application-uninstall-script?forum=winserverpowershell) it looks like the method `.uninstall()` only works when used with `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product`. But this means it will consider 32-bit software only and not 64-bit software.

So I wrote this few lines in order to uninstall Erlang, which is 64-bit:

```
# Check if a Software ins installed
function Check_Program_Installed($programName) {
    $x86_check = ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") |
                 Get-ItemProperty |
                 Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*$programName*" } |
                 Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString) |
                 Format-Table

    if (Test-Path 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall') {
        $x64_check = ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*$programName*" } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString) | Format-Table
    }
    if ($x86_check -and $x64_check -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "$programName is not installed on this computer" -ForegroundColor Green
        #continue
    } elseif ($x86_check -or $x64_check -ne $null) {
        Write-Host "On this computer is installed " -ForegroundColor Red
        $x86_check
        $x64_check

        $x86_check.uninstall()
        $x64_check.uninstall()
    }
}

# Erlang check
Write-Host "Checking if Erlang exist    " -NoNewline
Check_Program_Installed("Erlang")
Write-Host "The End: the script ends here" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

but unfortunately it returns me the error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.ps1:17 char:3
>   +         $x86_check.uninstall()
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> Method invocation failed because
>   [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal. Format.FormatStartData] does
>   not contain a method named 'Uninstall'. At
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.ps1:18 char:3
>   +         $x64_check.uninstall()
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

I believe the root cause it that there are `DisplayName` and `UninstallString` in the variable, right?

A way out I found is to use:

```
'"C:\Program Files\erl8.3\Uninstall.exe'" | cmd
```

in order to uninstall but this is not using the `.uninstall()` method which is what I want to use.

Is Microsoft saying that you can use `.uninstall()` only with 32-bit architecture and for 64-bit you need to find your own way out?

If so it's quite rudimentary

Comment: Don't use `Format-*` cmdlets for further _programmatic_ processing - these cmdlets are intended solely to create output for _display_.

Comment: that error message means that the `x86` version is not installed. you need to add a test for _each one_ of those reg keys. your current test is only for "one or the other".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The reply is NO.**

`.uninstall()` can only be used with `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product` and therefore will only uninstall 32-bit programs.

- [Source 1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0116b77a-6087-426a-913a-17a336b808bd/class-win32product-misses-a-program-listed-in-uninstall-a-program-console?forum=ITCG)
- [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882725/wmi-not-return-all-install-programs-on-windows-7-64)
- [Source 3](https://myrandomthoughts.co.uk/2015/07/win32_product/)
- [Source 4](https://overpoweredshell.com/SysAdmin-Basics-Getting-Installed-Software/)
- [Source 5](http://codeandkeep.com/Get-List-of-Installed-Applications/)

There might be an alternative way out uninstall both 32-bit and 64-bit program with:

```
Get-Package "*Erlang*"
```

At least finds the program but

```
Get-Package "*Erlang*" | Uninstall-Package -Force
```

won't uninstall