# "wmic product get name" shows different result from control panel

Tags: windows, wmic

When I execute `wmic product get name` from cmd, I got this

[image]

In control panel I got this

[image]

It's weird that Avast is missing from wmic command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stucked with the same question a few years ago. At this time, I've found only workarounds, not a good solution.
The reason often mentioned is the use of 32bit and 64bit. This couldn't confirmend at my systems.

My used workaround was to read the following regkeys:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

Today I would try the powershell wmi.

See also: [WMI "installed" query different from add/remove programs list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673233/wmi-installed-query-different-from-add-remove-programs-list)