# Trying to get all installed packages on Windows 2012R2 and Windows 2008 Server

Tags: package, windows-server-2008, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to retrieve all the installed packages on Windows Server (2012R2 and 2008). Win 2012 has PowerShell V4 and Win 2008 has PowerShell V3.

Tried using Poweshell command "Get-Package" but this works only for Powershell versions 5 and later.

Tried to follow this below links but not able to get any output.
https://powershell.org/2015/10/using-package-management-in-windows-powershell-v3/

Would appreciate if an alternate command can be provided for Powershell Version (3 and 4). Thank you for your time and effort in advance.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Package
Get-Package : The term 'Get-Package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Package
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Package:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PackageProvider | Select-Object -Property Name | Sort-Object -Property Name
Get-PackageProvider : The term 'Get-PackageProvider' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PackageProvider | Select-Object -Property Name | Sort-Object -Property Name
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-PackageProvider:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Command -Module PackageManagement | Select-Object -Property Name | Format-Wide -Column 2
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Package
Get-Package : The term 'Get-Package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Package
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Package:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\Administrator> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

I expect to get results like

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Package | select Name, Version

Name                                                                                         Version
----                                                                                         -------
Amazon SSM Agent                                                                             2.3.444.0
Amazon SSM Agent                                                                             2.3.444.0
AWS Tools for Windows                                                                        3.15.666
AWS PV Drivers                                                                               8.2.6
aws-cfn-bootstrap                                                                            1.4.31
Update for Windows Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.1903.4)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.291.1405.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.291.1225.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.291.1155.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.291.1077.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.291.1016.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.291.920.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.291.76.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.291.9.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.289.1652.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.289.1237.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.289.1157.0)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.289.1094.0)
Update for Windows Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.1902.2)
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.289.911.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_InstalledWin32Program | Select Name, Version, Vendor | ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 0):

You could look at wmi:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select Name, Version | Sort
```

Or

```
wmic product get name,version
```

But the best source might be uninstall registry keys. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673233/wmi-installed-query-different-from-add-remove-programs-list)

Comment: Thankyou @Abhinav - this is why I provided multiple options

Answer (score 0):

Remote Machine List you can get it from bellow command

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName MachineName